# My JDialog sometimes receives a redundant keystroke from the calling app ? (code provided)

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, netbeans-platform

I develop a complex music application in java (8) based on the Netbeans RCP 8.2 and I have a strange problem that occurs randomly.

I have a JFrame with a panel which contains many JComponents. I use the panel's InputMap/ActionMap to capture "a","b",...,"g" key presses and call an action.

The action retrieves the key char then shows a JDialog which contains a JTextField used to edit some text data.

Before showing the dialog with dialog.setVisible(true), the action calls dialog.prepare(char key) so that the JDialog can initialize itself before being shown. Actually dialog.prepare(char key) only appends the passed char (converted to uppercase) in the JTextField.

This works most of the time: I press for example "c" in the JFrame then the JDialog appears with "C" at the end of the JTextField.

But sometimes, maybe 1/20 times, I get "Cc" at the end of the JTextfield !

It's like the original key press event (which comes from a JComponent in the JFrame's panel and was processed using InputMap/ActionMap) was also redundantly processed by the JDialog.

I verified that it's not a keyboard hardware problem. I reproduced the issue on a second computer with Win8 (mine is Win10).

I tried without success 1/ using a KeyListener instead of InputMap/ActionMap
and 2/ use java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater() to append the key char in the JTextField.

I created a small independant app (see below) to reproduce the issue and facilitate debugging...but this small app works fine, I could not reproduce the issue :-( Then I compared again with my real app code, and it's *really* the same code, except the real app is a complete Netbeans RCP application.

So could it be that Netbeans RCP impacts the way Swing handle key events ? It looks odd to me...

I'm lost, any hint/suggested test would be greatly appreciated !

```
/**
 * Try to reproduce double key problem... Failed because this works OK !! :-(
 */
public class PbKeyDouble extends JFrame {

   MyDialog dialog;

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
            PbKeyDouble o = new PbKeyDouble();
            o.setVisible(true);
         }
      });
   }

   public PbKeyDouble() {
      // GUI INITIALIZATION

      // Add a basic panel
      JPanel panel = new JPanel();
      getContentPane().add(panel);
      panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 200));

      JButton button = new JButton("BUTTON");
      panel.add(button);
      // Button not used, it's only to simulate the real app where a component in the panel has the focus
      button.requestFocusInWindow();

      // If "A" or "B" key is pressed anywhere, MyAction.actionPerformed() will be called
      panel.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("A"), "MyAction");
      panel.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("B"), "MyAction");
      panel.getActionMap().put("MyAction", new MyAction());

      // Prepare JFrame
      setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      pack();
      setLocationRelativeTo(null);
   }

   private class MyAction extends AbstractAction {

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

         System.out.println("EDT? " + SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread());  // Always prints TRUE

         if (dialog == null) {
            dialog = new MyDialog();
         }

         // Retrieve the key used to trigger the action
         char c = e.getActionCommand().charAt(0);

         // Prepare the dialog (insert the char)
         dialog.prepare(c);

         // Show dialog
         dialog.setVisible(true);
      }
   }

   private class MyDialog extends JDialog {

      JTextField textfield;

      /**
       * A simple dialog with just a textfield.
       */
      public MyDialog() {
         textfield = new JTextField("Hello");
         textfield.setColumns(100);
         getContentPane().add(textfield);
         pack();
         setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      }

      /**
       * Append the key (uppercased) at the end of the textfield
       */
      public void prepare(char c) {
         String text = textfield.getText();
         textfield.setText(text + " " + Character.toUpperCase(c));
      }

      /**
       * Overridden to add a global key binding on ESC key to exit the dialog.
       * <p>
       * This is only to facilitate the test where I need to try many times the process pressing "a" ESC "a" ESC etc.
       *
       * @return
       */
      @Override
      protected JRootPane createRootPane() {
         JRootPane contentPane = new JRootPane();

         contentPane.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ESCAPE"), "actionCancel");
         contentPane.getActionMap().put("actionCancel", new AbstractAction("Cancel") {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
               setVisible(false);
            }
         });
         return contentPane;
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem, though it is still not logical to me. Explanation welcome !

> All Swing components should be created and modified on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT).

Yes, it was the case in my code and still it was not working...

To try to understand what happens I attached a KeyListener to the JTextField of the JDialog.

I found out that when it was working (key not doubled) my KeyListener received only a keyReleased() event. When it was not working (key doubled "Cc") my KeyListener received a keyTyped() event then keyReleased().

So I understand that AWT/Swing event handler mechanism "sends" each KeyEvent to the currently focused component (instead of to the component which the KeyEvent originates from). As I show the Dialog somewhere in the middle of the keyPressed/keyTyped/keyReleased sequence, sometimes the keyTyped was "wrongly" directed to the JTextField.

To solve this I executed the whole actionPerformed() code using SwingUtilities.invokeLater(), to make sure Dialog is shown after all EDT pending events are processed, and it seems to work so far...

I could find some good information in [Java keybinding](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) but what I don't understand is that it is recommended to use InputMap/ActionMap to avoid all the KeyListeners problems with focus changes etc. I used only InputMap/ActionMap and still it did not help...

So why InputMap does not react only to keyTyped() event ?

Answer (score 0):

> But sometimes, maybe 1/20 times, I get "Cc" at the end of the JTextfield !

Random issues are usually the result of threading issues.

All Swing components should be created and modified on the `Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)`.

The code from your main() method is not executed on the EDT which could be the problem.

The code to create the GUI should be wrapped in a `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)`.

Check out the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I thought too, EDT thread misuse. But indeed the UI code is really executed on the EDT thread, I checked it. I updated the sample code to add a SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread(), I also added invokeLater() in the main().